# Getting error when trying to return value to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

Im trying to return a value back to dropzone's javascript on success. Im using a return Json action and trying to build a url to direct to another view. My question, How do I return a value back to a javascript function and get the value?

Im getting an error like this when i try to find the value.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at u.<anonymous> (Upload:44)
at u.n.emit (dropzone:1)
at dropzone:1
```

when my code is like this:

```
                        myDropzone.on("queuecomplete",
                            function(data) {
                                this.removeAllFiles();

                                var res = JSON.parse(data);

                                var  url = "@Url.Action("OrderConfirmation","Upload", new
                                       {

                                           OrderNumber =  "45678"
                                       })";


                                window.location.replace(url);

                            });
```

This is return line of my action

```
   return Json(new {OrderNumber = orderNumber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllowGet` should not be part of the object returned, it is the second parameter to `Json()`.

```
return Json(new { OrderNumber = orderNumber }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Edit: Don't know much about dropzone, but I suspect `data` is already an object so `JSON.parse()` might be unnecessary.  At any rate, `data.OrderNumber` or `res.OrderNumber` should be the order number.

You can't use `@Url.Action` in javascript because that executes server-side, before the javascript is ever hit.  You need to do something like

```
var url = '/Upload/OrderConfirmation/' + data.OrderNumber;
```

or if you really need the URL built for you, put in a dummy query string parameter

```
var url = '@Url.Action("OrderConfirmation", "Upload", new { OrderNumber = XXXXX}"';
```

and then substitute "XXXXX" with the real order number in the `url` string.

Comment: Thanks for that. The other part of the question, how do i read that value in the javascript?

Comment: Thanks so much. I believe that got it.  Man, I have to got to get better at javascript. Is there a support group for that? lol

Comment: Im getting a new error when trying the above code . I get a data is undefined. Any idea why?